# Identifying covalent character in ionic compounds when varying multiple ions

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, ionic-compounds, halides, covalent-compounds

By Fajans' rules, we can easily find out which compound shows covalent character.

Example: Among $\ce{NaCl}$, $\ce{MgCl2}$, $\ce{AlCl3}$ which one is more covalent?

Answer: There is a point in Fajans' rules that the compound which has more charge number that compound will show covalent character. In $\ce{AlCl3}$, Al has the highest oxidation state (+3) so it will show more covalent character than $\ce{NaCl}$ and $\ce{MgCl2}$.

The point is that since all three compounds I have mentioned have chlorine in common, it was easy to catch the solution but if the compounds were given as $\ce{NaF}$ and $\ce{LiCl}$, which one shows more covalent character, and how can we apply Fajans' rules?

Answer (score 4):

You will have to consider two factors here: polarising power of the cation and polarisability of the anion. 
There is more than one part of Fajan’s rule(Source-J. D. Lee, Concise Inorganic Chemistry):

> 1. A small positive ion favours covalency.
> 2. A large negative ion favours covalency.
> 3. Large charges on either ion, or both ions, favours covalency.
> 4. Polarisation and hence covalency is favoured if the positive ion does not have noble has configuration.

According to these, the $\ce{Li+}$ ion is more polarising than $\ce{Na+}$ ion, and $\ce{Cl-}$ ion is more polarisable than $\ce{F-}$ ion.

Since both factors support it, $\ce{LiCl}$ is more covalent than $\ce{NaF}$.

Somtimes, like in your question, both the factors support each other. Sometimes, when they are opposite, like in the case of $\ce{LiF}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$, it is tough to determine relative covalency using Fajan’s rule.

Comment: does that mean that d block elements (Transition elements) are more ionic than alkali metals and alkaline earth metal compounds ?

Comment: @Tanuj actually it means the opposite; the d-block elements are generally smaller than the corresponding alkali metals/ alkaline earth metals.

Comment: Okay , got it .